# Issue with Ionic/Angular $watch fired before promise function filling data from pouchdb

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, promise, pouchdb

I don't really know where to start describing this issue.
It was extremely hard to look for some info on the internet.

I have this Ionic App (which uses AngularJS) which save data to a PouchDB local database.

In the main page, I have a nested-view containing, on the left column (first controller) the list of previously saved data, and in the center column (second controller) the details of the item the user selected from the left.

This is the issue: when the user clicks one of the items from the left column, in the center of the page starts a new controller which should displays the detailed info but it shows empty inputs.
Clicking the same item again, all inputs are filled.

I have added a $watch to the variabile loaded, logging the value, and I have done that too in the callback function.
When the user click the first time this is the result:

```
($watch) myvar has changed from undefined to undefined
(setValues) myvar.name: test
```

This is what happens when I click another time:

```
($watch) myvar has changed from undefined to _id: 8ee32942-1c61-865b-2cd0-8d5b3d4a3082; name: test
```

The same issue happens also loading the items on the left.

I load my data from a local PouchDB. Instead of actually querying the db, I have tried to replace that with

```
return Promise.resolve({'_id': 'test001', 'name': 'test'});
```

and guess what...it works!

So now the question is: where is the issue? Is the controller? Is pouchdb? Is Ionic Framework? Is the loading function?

Here's finally some code:

```
$scope.$watch('myvar', function( newValue, oldValue ) {
  console.log('($watch) myvar has changed from ' + printMyvar(oldValue) + ' to ' + printMyvar(newValue));
});

var printMyvar = function (var_to_print) {
  var s = 'undefined';
  if (var_to_print) {
    s = '_id: ' + var_to_print._id;
    s += '; name: ' + var_to_print.name;
  }
  return s;
}

var setValues = function (doc) {
  console.log('(setValues) name: ' + doc._id);
  $scope.myvar = doc;
};

$scope.isNew = ($stateParams.extId === 'new');

if ($scope.isNew) {
  $scope.myvar = { '_id': '', 'name': '' };
}  
else {
  Database.get( $stateParams.extId )
    .then( setValues )
    .catch( $scope.logError );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please read Section **Why**

https://github.com/angular-pouchdb/angular-pouchdb

PouchDB is asynchronous, you will often need to call $scope.$apply() before changes are reflected on the UI

```
angular.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
  var db = $window.PouchDB('db');
  db.get('id')
    .then(function(res) {
      // Binding may/may not be updated depending on whether a digest cycle has
      // been triggered elsewhere as Angular is unaware that `get` has resolved.
      $scope.one = res;
    });

  var db2 = $window.PouchDB('db2');
  db.get('id')
    .then(function(res) {
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        // Value has been bound within Angular's context, so a digest will be
        // triggered and the DOM updated
        $scope.two = res;
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Mauro! You saved my days! Adding $scope.$apply make the whole thing works.